# Probability as understood in the Canonical Ensemble

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I have a couple of doubts with regard to the probability as understood in the Canonical Ensemble. Let's consider the following problem:

> A system consisting of $N$ non-interacting, identical and
>   distinguishable spins with $S=1/2$ and magnetic momentum $\mu$ on an
>   external magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is in equilibrium with a bath at
>   temperature $T$. Find the probability $P_n$ that the system has $n$ spins
>   aligned with $\vec{B}$.

For each particle, I see that the accessible energy states would be $\varepsilon_+=-\mu B = -\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon_-=\mu B = \varepsilon$, so the partition functions of the particle and the system would be, respectively, $Z_1=e^{-\varepsilon \beta}+e^{\varepsilon \beta}=2 \cosh(\varepsilon \beta)$ and $Z_N=Z_1^N$. Thus, the probabilities of a certain particle being on the state $+$ and $-$ would be: $P_+=\frac{e^{-\varepsilon}}{Z_1}$ and $P_-=\frac{e^{\varepsilon}}{Z_1}$. On the other hand, the energy of the system if $n_+=n$ would be $E_n=\varepsilon_+  n_++\varepsilon_-n_-=\varepsilon(N-2n)$.

Then, with regard to the probability asked in the statement, which of these interpretations of would be correct?

**1.** By Laplacian concept of probability:
$$P=\frac{\text{number of microstates with} \space n_+=n}{\text{number of microstates}}$$

**2.** As the energy of the system is $E_n=\varepsilon_+  n_++\varepsilon_-n_-=\varepsilon(N-2n)$, then:
$$P=\frac{\text{number of microstates with} \space E=E_n=\varepsilon(N-2n)}{\text{number of microstates}}$$

(not sure about this, cause there are certain microstates which gives the same system-energy values...)

**3.** Again, as the energy of the system is $E_n=\varepsilon_+  n_++\varepsilon_-n_-=\varepsilon(N-2n)$, using the formula of the probability in terms of the Canonical Partition Function: 
$$P_n=\frac{e^{-\beta E_n}}{Z^N}$$

(but, again, not sure about this because of the degeneration of some system-energy levels...)

**4.** Using the Binomial Distribution: $n_+\sim\text{Bin}(P_+,N)$, so $P_n={N \choose n} (P_+)^n(P_-)^{N-n}$

**5.** Others?

Comment: The correct answer is 4. The probability of observing a particular configuration $\sigma$ of the spins is $e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}/Z$, where $H(\sigma)$ is the energy of the configuration $\sigma$ and $Z=\sum_\sigma e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}$ is the partition function. So, the probability associated to a given collection $A$ of configurations (in your case, those having $n_+$ "up" spins) is $\sum_{\sigma\in A} e^{-\beta H(\sigma)}/Z$. In your case, all conf. with $n_+$ spins have the same energy, so you get the probability of any of those configurations times the number of such configurations.

Comment: Thanks, but why the others are not correct?

Comment: Because, in general, the probability of $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are different (they only coincide when $H(\sigma)=H(\sigma')$). Your formulas 1 and 2 assume equiprobability, while in your formula 3 you are forgetting the degeneracy (the probability distribution is on configurations, not energy levels).

Comment: That makes sense for 3. However, according to the fundamental assumption of statistical mechanics, an isolated system in a given macrostate is equally likely to be found in any of its microstates over time. So, why could we not assume equiprobability in cases 1 and 2 for the microstates?

Comment: It is only in the microcanonical (that is, fixed energy) ensemble that all microstates have the same probability. Here you are considering a fixed temperature ensemble. (In particular, your system is *not* isolated: it must exchange heat in order to maintain a fixed temperature!)